# Error in PYTHON OCR Tesseract

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

When running my python OCR script from CMD, I get this error. Is it a problem with the picture or my code??

**error log**

```
D:\Documents\Everything Programming\_Not Hacking\Bots\Discord Bots\python img recog>imgrecog.py
  File "D:\Documents\Everything Programming\_Not Hacking\Bots\Discord Bots\python img recog\imgrecog.py", line 3
    print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('C:\Users\[MY NAME]\Desktop\letrs.jpg')))
                                                ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

**code**

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('C:\Users\[MY NAME]\Desktop\letrs.jpg')))
```

Comment: You just need to escape your forward slashes.  i.e. `Image.open('C:\\Users\\[MY NAME]\\Desktop\\letrs.jpg')` or use a raw string `Image.open(r'C:\Users\[MY NAME]\Desktop\letrs.jpg')`. The character '\' indicates the start of an escape sequence, so it's trying to interpret `\U` and `\[` as characters and failing

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Use slashes `/` instead of backslashes `\` and you should be fine.
Your main problem es de folder ,`\Users` which is trying to be interpreted because of the `\U`. So just stay away from backslashes when coding and your code should work.
Other solution is to put double backslash like `'\\Users'` but why bother.